# How to install my ATI graphic card?

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

my laptop has a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650, and I've tried many ways to install the drivers but nothing has worked for me, how can I do it?

Also, I'm not sure why but when I put `'lspci -vvnn | grep VGA'` it showes me this:

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI 
 RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250] [1002:9712] (prog-if 00 [VGA 
 controller])

VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI 
 Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6550M] [1002:68c1] (prog-if 
 00 [VGA controller])
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to install `xserver-xorg-video-radeon`, the driver works great in trusty

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

`xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/307104/367165) is a driver for NVIDIA.

Comment: You may need to `modprobe radeon` as well. On my machine the kernel dosen't load the radeon KMS driver for some reason so X won't use the radeon X driver.

Comment: If you've previously installed the fglrx driver it blacklists the radeon kernel module, so you'll need to check in /etc/modprobe.d and see if a file blacklists the radeon driver. if so, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

AMD still continues to support the ATI Radeon series. To download the drivers go here:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/download
The driver is dated Apr-2014 (as of Apr 30, 2014)

Comment: The question was not how to download driver files but how to install drivers. Can you expand your answer to include that information?

Answer (score -1):

Well, Radeon has officially dropped support for the HD series, so you'll have to use the open-source driver.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot #This will reboot your computer, so save any open files first.
```

That should get you going.

Credit and thanks to Bashing-om and QIII from the Ubuntu Forums for [helping me get my card working](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2152930&referrerid=1739423).
This has been tested with a Radeon HD 4350.

Comment: "Nouveau" is for nVidia cards, not Radeon. Please correct.

Comment: xserver-xorg-video-nouveau provides support for NVIDIA Riva, TNT, GeForce, and Quadro cards. Not ATI Mobility Radeon HD cards