# unity hangs after installing AMD Catalyst™ 13.6 LINUX Beta Driver

Tags: drivers, 13.04, video, radeon, toshiba-satellite

I'm trying to install the video driver for my Toshiba Satellite L725D-A7280.

`lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(vga)"` gives:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Kabini [Radeon HD 8400] [1002:9830]
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:fa85]
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI device [1002:9840]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device [1002:9840]
```

I upgraded the kernel to 3.10.1 to get my wireless working.  [rtl8188ee make errors on 13.04 (L75D-A7280)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322731/rtl8188ee-make-errors-on-13-04-l75d-a7280)

After upgrading the kernel and using [these drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-6LINBetaDriver.aspx), `unity` hangs on login and only shows the cursor and the background.

After starting fresh with the kernel upgrade and doing [this](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=12447) `sudo X -configure` and `mv` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` works but with bad performance.

I'm still very noob.  How can I install the video driver for my laptop?

**short-term fix**

This gets rid of video errors in unity [How to install my ATI graphic card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307103/how-to-install-my-ati-graphic-card?rq=1)

but performance is still bad.

**more limping & information**

13.6b is not compatible with kernel > 3.8, so that's why it won't work (even though I couldn't get it to work with the original kernel, so help with the 3.8 kernel would be much appreciated)

As per day to day performance, the problem is really 3d, as 2d is pretty sweet, so to keep my desktop running smoothly, I [installed CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://www.itworld.com/software/354000/install-compizconfig-settings-manager-ubuntu-1304), and [turned off animations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203075/howto-disable-3d-effects-compiz-on-12-10).

I also did [this](http://followthegeeks.com/compiz-is-consuming-too-much-cpu-heres-the-solution/) and `reboot`ed.

Should tide me over until my nic's on 3.8 and/or 13.6 comes out of beta.

Comment: This ubuntu version is unsupported, and might be closed as off-topic. try upgrading :D